# Access NSMutableDictionary created in one class from another ARC iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, automatic-ref-counting, nsmutabledictionary

If the users checks something in a UITableViewCell I use this method to make a check in an NSMutableDictionary *checkDict:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[checkDict objectForKey:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] isEqualToString:@"Check"]) {
        [checkDict setObject:@"NOCheck" forKey:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [table reloadData];
    }
    else 
    {
        [checkDict setObject:@"Check" forKey:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [table reloadData];
    }
}
```

In this class I set the property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *checkDict;
```

I want to populate the next view with information from those with "Check" as objects set in the checkDict MutableDictionary. How do I access this MutableDict from the next class? If I instantiate the previous class containing the code above, I get null for checkDict. I am using ARC, and StoryBoard. Is there a way to do this other than:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:checkDict forKey:@"CheckDict"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways:

1. You can `create a common live data manager` which will be `a singleton class` that will hold this dictionary and which you can access at any place using this singleton class.
2. In above apprach, you `can use App Delegate to store the dictionary`(with setter/getter) and access it using [[UIApplication sharedAppliation] delegate] object.
3. You `can pass this dictionary object to the other view` object when you create(alloc/init) the view. But for this approach we should be creating the view from the same class in which we have this dictionary.
4. As you are having this dictionary declared as property so you `can create the reference of this class in the view class` where you want to access this dictionary, and then access it using the class reference.

Thanks,